# Adb does not detect android device on Windows - Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging, adb-drivers

**Problem**

Simple, adb does not recognize my android tablet - `Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2`

Note: I can access the storage from explorer, that is not the issue. Issue is adb does not recognize it. Hence unable to debug on the device.

***This is not a duplicate. Have exhaustively tried solutions in all similar posts on SO.***

**Things already tried:**

1. Installed drivers from [http://support.lenovo.com/](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS022366) and tried updating from device manager. - It always says drivers are already up to date. Also tried reinstalling but it automatically defaults back to `MTP Device`
2. Installed `Intel USB Drivers` setup from suggestions on this [lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Android-Ecosystem-Developers/ADB-drivers-for-Yoga-tablet-2-pro/td-p/1811434) and installed.
3. Updated `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and adding the vendor id `0x17ef`.
4. Updated `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and adding exaustive list of all vendor ids from [here](https://apkudo.com/?p=676).

None of the above satisfied adb and the device is still not showing up when executing `adb devices`.

What did I miss? or what else can i try?

Comment: Setting-> Storage -> Select Media device

Comment: All those things tried.

Comment: use third-party apps like `Moborobo`  will help you

Comment: can you add a link to the suggested tool and give a brief of how it works?

Comment: Try `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` in the console.

Comment: did that after every new thing i tried. does not make it work.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you enable the debuging on your device. Did you?

Comment: That was funny. of course, i did.

Comment: You could try to install [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Zn9Y8ZbKwAdDVCeV9FU0F0Nlk/view?usp=sharing) driver. It did work for me on a device I had troubles with. Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome... that worked! You might want to post it as an answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also found another [Universal Windows ADB Driver Tool](http://koush.com/post/universal-adb-driver) for Windows users. This one is downloadable from a proper website, if we do not want to go with the anonymous source in the answer I've accepted earlier (although it did work for me). This tool is open source and its source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver).

Download from clockworkmod.com - [Here](http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi)

Download from author's GitHub repo - [Here](http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi)

> If you do any Android development on Windows, this will be
>   ridiculously handy. Every manufacturer ships their own ADB driver on
>   Windows, so getting new devices running on ADB is a royal pain. I've
>   compiled a list of most phone vendor and product ids and rolled them
>   into a single driver.
>
> You can grab the download [here](http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi). And the source is available on [Github](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver).

Source : http://koush.com/post/universal-adb-driver

Comment: This answer is being discussed on meta: [Link only answers recommending to run an executable from unverifiable source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332860/link-only-answers-recommending-to-run-an-executable-from-unverifiable-source?cb=1)

Comment: Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Ferrybig, actually the meta topic you linked was discussing another currently deleted answer to this question which was the accepted answer at the time.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately. Lenovo S8 tablet and Windows 7.